# Track project's particular local folder with remote branch's particular folder

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I want to connect one particular folder of local repo to remote repo's particular folder on github.com

Sample local and remote structure of my project. (CodeIgniter/PHP structure for example)

**My local Repo structure =>**

```
C:\wamp64\www\myproject\
    admincp
        assests_admin
        index.php
    application
        admincp
            config
            controllers
            models
            views
        front
            config
            controllers
            models
            views
        language
    assests_front
    uploads
    userfiles
    vendor
    index.php
```

**My Git Remote Repo structure (Private Repo) =>** In remote repo, I have just following folders.

Also I have just `master` branch here.

```
https://github.com/username/myproject/
    assests_admin
    admincp
        config
        controllers
        models
        views
    assests_front
    front
        config
        controllers
        models
        views
```

Now I want to track local `C:\wamp64\www\myproject\application\admincp` folder (with all it's subfolders and files) with remote repo `https://github.com/username/myproject/admincp` folder and it's all contents.

Same as track local `C:\wamp64\www\myproject\application\front` folder (with all it's subfolders and files) with remote repo `https://github.com/username/myproject/front` folder and it's all contents.

**Que 1=>** Is this type of scenario possible?

**Que 2=>** If possible then, In which local folder's I have to run `$git init` commands to achieve above scenario? After that which `config` and `remote add` commands to run? Please let me know the complete procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `admincp` is a local  Git repository (meaning you have made `git init .` in that folder, add and commit), you could:

- push `admincp` to its own GitHub repository
- reference that repository in your `myproject` parent GitHub repo, with `admincp` as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: I have already created `https://github.com/username/myproject/tree/master/admincp` in Github and it's all files are up-to-date as of today with my local files (because I was using Github's drag and drop files), But now I want to do it with command line from Git Bash. In local I have done `git init` in `C:\wamp64\www\myproject\application\admincp` folder and then `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/myproject/tree/master/admincp`. After that when I do `git status` it says `Untracked files: config/ controllers/ models/ views/` But I have already those files in github.com.

Comment: @Viren `https://github.com/username/myproject/tree/master/admincp` is not a valid repository: it is a subfolder within the repository `myproject`. In my answer, I was referring to "its own GitHub repository", that is: `https://github.com/username/admincp`. You will then add it to your main repo (`myproject`) with a `cd myproject; git submodule add https://github.com/username/admincp`

Comment: Thanks for your answer & explanation. It helped to understand my problem. I have to just follow your instructions as your explanation.